# How to isolate SQLAlchemy session between tests and tested code?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask, SQLAlchemy and Flask-SQLALchemy. I've stumbled a few times at issues resulting from the fact that the tested code and the tests share the same SQLAlchemy session.

Here's an example application:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite://'
db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String())


@app.route('/set_name/<user_id>', methods=['POST'])
def set_name(user_id):
    user = User.query.get(user_id)
    user.name = request.form['name']

    # we don't commit the session, so the name change is only local.
    # db.session.commit()

    return user.name
```

And example test that uses separate contexts for the test preparation code and the tested code:

```
def test_set_name_different_context():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        user = User(name='a')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        user_id = user.id

    client = app.test_client()
    client.post('/set_name/{}'.format(user_id), data={'name': 'b'})

    with app.app_context():
        user = User.query.get(user_id)
        assert user.name == 'a'
```

In the test above, as we expect the name change doesn't persist.

But if we change the test above to use a single context (to avoid boilerplate):

```
def test_set_name_same_context():
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

        user = User(name='a')
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        user_id = user.id

        client = app.test_client()
        client.post('/set_name/{}'.format(user_id), data={'name': 'b'})

        user = User.query.get(user_id)
        # This fails, because we are in the same app context, we use the 
        # same session both for the test code and the tested code.
        assert user.name == 'a'
```

The test fails, because the SQLAlchemy session of the test code and the tested code is the same one.

While it's expected and makes sense once you understand how session scoping works in Flask-SQLAlchemy, I still wonder if there is a way to have a different session for the tested code and the test code without all the boilerplate.

Comment: are you trying to avoid testing on your production or development db i.e you want a db that is reset for each test case?

Comment: No. It's not about isolating the database, it's specifically about SQLAlchemy's sessions.

Comment: Yeah I did some more research after posting and I am starting to understand what you are trying to do but can't really be any help. It is an interesting problem.

Comment: Did you found a solution in the meantime? I have the same problem.